# Changing Routes on button click

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am a beginner in node.js and express. And I need some help with my code.
I have an app.js file where my server code is written. When it starts, it loads an index.html file that have some text and buttons.When a button is clicked, I want the URL to change so it matches one of my express routes.
For eg: When "delete" button is clicked, I want to delete an element from an object. And when "get" button is clicked, I want to get an element from the same object.

I tried history.pushState() and it turned out to be a mess.

Here is my app.js code:

```
const expressions = {1: "happy", 2: "sad"}

app.get("/expressions/:id", (req, res, next)=>{
      res.send(expression[req.params.id]);
});
app.delete("/expressions/:id", (req, res, next)=>{
      delete expressions[req.params.id];
});
```

Here is my index.html code:

```
<button type="button" value"delete">delete</button>
<button type="button" value"get">get</button>
```

I really need some help with some explanation. I searched it but i didn't get what i want. I don't know if I missed any helpful resources.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another page or stay in the same page? Anyway, if i understand well your problem, you have to make AJAX requests.

Comment: why do you want to change the URL in the browser??
You need to listen for click event on both of the buttons, and depending on which button was clicked you need to make a ajax request to your node server(This will not change the URL).

Comment: But it will not change the URL, How the express 'get' request will launch if it didn't get any request?